# Facing Problem in Applying Convolutional Kernel?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using TensorFlow Keras for the implementation. I want to use convolutional Kernel in a specific way on my input matrix. Let me explain with the figures:

**My Input Matrix:**

[image]

Want to Apply the Convolutional Kernel in the following way:

**Step1**
[image]

**Step2**
[image]

**Step3**
[image]

and So on. So what strategy should I use?

Comment: This is a typical use case for a 1D CNN (temporal convolution). See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D.. The height of your kernel would be your window size while the width remains fixed and you will use a stride of 1, for example.

Comment: @AloneTogether Conv1D cover one dimension. I want to apply CNN on two dimensions (Width and Height e.g., kernel = (5 * 6)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `kernel width` to `input matrix width`.

Example:

```
input_matrix = tf.random.normal(shape=(26, 6, 1))
# input_matrix.shape [26, 6, 1]


n_filters = 1
kernel_height = 5
kernel_width = input_matrix.shape[1]
output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(kernel_height, kernel_width))(tf.expand_dims(input_matrix, axis=0))

#output.shape: [1, 22, 1, 1] (because of valid padding)
```

Comment: my input shape is 24*6*1. I want to apply CNN kernel 5*6. I don't want to reshape my input.

Comment: Edited for your specific input shape.